# How to recover Git objects damaged by hard disk failure?

Tags: git, corruption, data-recovery

I have had a hard disk failure which resulted in some files of a Git repository getting damaged. When running `git fsck --full` I get the following output:

```
error: .git/objects/pack/pack-6863e0a0e4b4ded6090fac5d12eba6ca7346b19c.pack SHA1 checksum mismatch
error: index CRC mismatch for object 6c8cae4994b5ec7891ccb1527d30634997a978ee from .git/objects/pack/pack-6863e0a0e4b4ded6090fac5d12eba6ca7346b19c.pack at offset 97824129
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid code lengths set)
error: cannot unpack 6c8cae4994b5ec7891ccb1527d30634997a978ee from .git/objects/pack/pack-6863e0a0e4b4ded6090fac5d12eba6ca7346b19c.pack at offset 97824129
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid stored block lengths)
error: failed to read object 0dcf6723cc69cc7f91d4a7432d0f1a1f05e77eaa at offset 276988017 from .git/objects/pack/pack-6863e0a0e4b4ded6090fac5d12eba6ca7346b19c.pack
fatal: object 0dcf6723cc69cc7f91d4a7432d0f1a1f05e77eaa is corrupted
```

I have backups of the repository, but the only backup that includes the pack file has it already damaged. So I think that I have to find out a way to retrieve the single objects from different backups and somehow instruct Git to produce a new pack with only correct objects.

Can you please give me hints how to fix my repository?

Comment: This just happened to me. I do not want to mess up with git objects... so re-cloned the project from remote repository into a new folder, and then just copy over all files from my problematic repositories (excluding the `.git` folder of course) into the freshly cloned repo... and then did `git status` in the new repo... git correctly detects all affected changes to my files and I can start my work again.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

In some previous backups, your bad objects may have been packed in different files or may be loose objects yet. So your objects may be recovered.

It seems there are a few bad objects in your database. So you could do it the manual way.

Because of `git hash-object`, `git mktree` and `git commit-tree` do not write the objects because they are found in the pack, then start doing this:

```
mv .git/objects/pack/* <somewhere>
for i in <somewhere>/*.pack; do
  git unpack-objects -r < $i
done
rm <somewhere>/*
```

(Your packs are moved out from the repository, and unpacked again in it; only the good objects are now in the database)

You can do:

```
git cat-file -t 6c8cae4994b5ec7891ccb1527d30634997a978ee
```

and check the type of the object.

If the type is blob: retrieve the contents of the file from previous backups (with `git show` or `git cat-file` or `git unpack-file`; then you may `git hash-object -w` to rewrite the object in your current repository.

If the type is tree: you could use `git ls-tree` to recover the tree from previous backups; then `git mktree` to write it again in your current repository.

If the type is commit: the same with `git show`, `git cat-file` and `git commit-tree`.

Of course, I would backup your original working copy before starting this process.

Also, take a look at [How to Recover Corrupted Blob Object](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.10.1/howto/recover-corrupted-blob-object.txt).

Comment: Thank you, that saved me! I will post my exact steps as a separate answer.

Comment: Just a correction: the command for ends with "done" and not "end".

Comment: i'm trying to do this but `.git/objects/pack/` is empty

Comment: for me a ; was missing after git unpack-objects -r < $i

Comment: @mithrandir: if you put the 'done' in the previous line: yes, you need a semicolon. If you type exactly what I wrote, you don't.

Comment: I'm facing this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38770736/575643 I tried your solution but couldn't fix that, do you have a clue how to fix that?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! shortcut answer: 1) move the bad file to another location 2) run from original location command `git unpack-objects -r < path_of_the_moved_bad_file.pack`

Answer (score 41):

[Banengusk](/users/16135/banengusk/) was putting me on the right track. For further reference, I want to post the steps I took to fix my repository corruption. I was lucky enough to find all needed objects either in older packs or in repository backups.

```bash
# Unpack last non-corrupted pack
$ mv .git/objects/pack .git/objects/pack.old
$ git unpack-objects -r < .git/objects/pack.old/pack-012066c998b2d171913aeb5bf0719fd4655fa7d0.pack
$ git log
fatal: bad object HEAD

$ cat .git/HEAD 
ref: refs/heads/master

$ ls .git/refs/heads/

$ cat .git/packed-refs 
# pack-refs with: peeled 
aa268a069add6d71e162c4e2455c1b690079c8c1 refs/heads/master

$ git fsck --full 
error: HEAD: invalid sha1 pointer aa268a069add6d71e162c4e2455c1b690079c8c1
error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
missing blob 75405ef0e6f66e48c1ff836786ff110efa33a919
missing blob 27c4611ffbc3c32712a395910a96052a3de67c9b
dangling tree 30473f109d87f4bcde612a2b9a204c3e322cb0dc

# Copy HEAD object from backup of repository
$ cp repobackup/.git/objects/aa/268a069add6d71e162c4e2455c1b690079c8c1 .git/objects/aa
# Now copy all missing objects from backup of repository and run "git fsck --full" afterwards
# Repeat until git fsck --full only reports dangling objects

# Now garbage collect repo
$ git gc
warning: reflog of 'HEAD' references pruned commits
warning: reflog of 'refs/heads/master' references pruned commits
Counting objects: 3992, done.
Delta compression using 2 threads.
fatal: object bf1c4953c0ea4a045bf0975a916b53d247e7ca94 inconsistent object length (6093 vs 415232)
error: failed to run repack

# Check reflogs...
$ git reflog

# ...then clean
$ git reflog expire --expire=0 --all

# Now garbage collect again
$ git gc       
Counting objects: 3992, done.
Delta compression using 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3970/3970), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3992/3992), done.
Total 3992 (delta 2060), reused 0 (delta 0)
Removing duplicate objects: 100% (256/256), done.
# Done!
```

Comment: Adding to this: If the backup has the missing files in a pack, the proper way to get a blob out of the pack is 'git cat-file blob <SHA1> > file.dat', and to get it back into the damaged repo, do 'git hash-object -w file.dat', as in Daniel's answer.

Comment: How do you find the last non-corrupted pack ? thanks

Answer (score 26):

Try the following commands at first (re-run again if needed):

```
$ git fsck --full
$ git gc
$ git gc --prune=today
$ git fetch --all
$ git pull --rebase
```

And then you you still have the problems, try can:

- remove all the corrupt objects, e.g.

  ```
  fatal: loose object 91c5...51e5 (stored in .git/objects/06/91c5...51e5) is corrupt
  $ rm -v .git/objects/06/91c5...51e5
  ```
- remove all the empty objects, e.g.

  ```
  error: object file .git/objects/06/91c5...51e5 is empty
  $ find .git/objects/ -size 0 -exec rm -vf "{}" \;
  ```
- check a "broken link" message by:

  ```
  git ls-tree 2d9263c6d23595e7cb2a21e5ebbb53655278dff8
  ```

  This will tells you what file the corrupt blob came from!
- to recover file, you might be really lucky, and it may be the version that you already have checked out in your working tree:

  ```
  git hash-object -w my-magic-file
  ```

  again, and if it outputs the missing SHA1 (4b945..) you're now all done!
- assuming that it was some older version that was broken, the easiest way to do it is to do:

  ```
  git log --raw --all --full-history -- subdirectory/my-magic-file
  ```

  and that will show you the whole log for that file (please realize that the tree you had may not be the top-level tree, so you need to figure out which subdirectory it was in on your own), then you can now recreate the missing object with hash-object again.
- to get a list of all refs with missing commits, trees or blobs:

  ```
  $ git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' | while read ref; do git rev-list --objects $ref >/dev/null || echo "in $ref"; done
  ```

  It may not be possible to remove some of those refs using the regular branch -d or tag -d commands, since they will die if git notices the corruption. So use the plumbing command git update-ref -d $ref instead. Note that in case of local branches, this command may leave stale branch configuration behind in .git/config. It can be deleted manually (look for the [branch "$ref"] section).
- After all refs are clean, there may still be broken commits in the reflog. You can clear all reflogs using git reflog expire --expire=now --all. If you do not want to lose all of your reflogs, you can search the individual refs for broken reflogs:

  ```
  $ (echo HEAD; git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)') | while read ref; do git rev-list -g --objects $ref >/dev/null || echo "in $ref"; done
  ```

  (Note the added -g option to git rev-list.) Then, use git reflog expire --expire=now $ref on each of those.
  When all broken refs and reflogs are gone, run git fsck --full in order to check that the repository is clean. Dangling objects are Ok.

---

**Below you can find advanced usage of commands which potentially can cause lost of your data in your git repository if not used wisely, so make a backup before you accidentally do further damages to your git. Try on your own risk if you know what you're doing.**

---

To pull the current branch on top of the upstream branch after fetching:

```
$ git pull --rebase
```

You also may try to checkout new branch and delete the old one:

```
$ git checkout -b new_master origin/master
```

---

To find the corrupted object in git for removal, try the following command:

```
while [ true ]; do f=`git fsck --full 2>&1|awk '{print $3}'|sed -r 's/(^..)(.*)/objects\/\1\/\2/'`; if [ ! -f "$f" ]; then break; fi; echo delete $f; rm -f "$f"; done
```

For OSX, use `sed -E` instead of `sed -r`.

---

Other idea is to unpack all objects from pack files to regenerate all objects inside .git/objects, so try to run the following commands within your repository:

```
$ cp -fr .git/objects/pack .git/objects/pack.bak
$ for i in .git/objects/pack.bak/*.pack; do git unpack-objects -r < $i; done
$ rm -frv .git/objects/pack.bak
```

---

If above doesn't help, you may try to rsync or copy the git objects from another repo, e.g.

```
$ rsync -varu git_server:/path/to/git/.git local_git_repo/
$ rsync -varu /local/path/to/other-working/git/.git local_git_repo/
$ cp -frv ../other_repo/.git/objects .git/objects
```

---

To fix the broken branch when trying to checkout as follows:

```
$ git checkout -f master
fatal: unable to read tree 5ace24d474a9535ddd5e6a6c6a1ef480aecf2625
```

Try to remove it and checkout from upstream again:

```
$ git branch -D master
$ git checkout -b master github/master
```

In case if git get you into detached state, checkout the `master` and merge into it the detached branch.

---

Another idea is to rebase the existing master recursively:

```
$ git reset HEAD --hard
$ git rebase -s recursive -X theirs origin/master
```

---

See also:

- [Some tricks to reconstruct blob objects in order to fix a corrupted repository.](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/recover-corrupted-blob-object.txt)
- [How to fix a broken repository?](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#fix-broken-repo)
- [How to remove all broken refs from a repository?](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#salvage)
- [How to fix corrupted git repository? (seeques)](http://www.seeques.com/24667777/how-to-fix-corrupted-git-repository.html)
- [How to fix corrupted git repository? (qnundrum)](http://qnundrum.com/answer.php?q=852196)
- [Error when using SourceTree with Git: 'Summary' failed with code 128: fatal: unable to read tree](http://answer.techwikihow.com/759224/error-sourcetree-git-summary-failed-code-128-fatal-unable-read-tree.html)
- [Recover A Corrupt Git Bare Repository](http://rewoo.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/recover-a-corrupt-git-bare-repository/)
- [Recovering a damaged git repository](http://miriup.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=88:recovering-a-damaged-git-repository&catid=8:linux&Itemid=25)
- [How to fix git error: object is empy / corrupt](http://vincesalvino.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/git-empty-files-corrupt-objects-and.html)
- [How to diagnose and fix git fatal: unable to read tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870895/how-to-diagnose-and-fix-git-fatal-unable-to-read-tree)
- [How to deal with this git error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507463/how-to-deal-with-this-git-error)
- [How to fix corrupted git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678853/how-to-fix-corrupted-git-repository/18687206)
- [How do I 'overwrite', rather than 'merge', a branch on another branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624357/git-how-to-overwrite-rather-than-merge-a-branch-on-another-branch)
- [How to replace master branch in git, entirely, from another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862590/how-to-replace-master-branch-in-git-entirely-from-another-branch)
- [Git: "Corrupt loose object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254389/git-corrupt-loose-object)
- [Git reset = fatal: unable to read tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515101/git-reset-fatal-unable-to-read-tree)

Comment: The  qnundrum.com link is broken: *"404. Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server."*. And possibly the www.seeques.com one as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For me `rm -v .git/objects/06/91c5...51e5` was required to fix a broken object in my repository

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps I followed to recover from a corrupt blob object.

1) Identify corrupt blob

```
git fsck --full
  error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
  error: sha1 mismatch 241091723c324aed77b2d35f97a05e856b319efd
  error: 241091723c324aed77b2d35f97a05e856b319efd: object corrupt or missing
  ...
```

Corrupt blob is **241091723c324aed77b2d35f97a05e856b319efd**

2) Move corrupt blob to a safe place (just in case)

```
mv .git/objects/24/1091723c324aed77b2d35f97a05e856b319efd ../24/
```

3) Get parent of corrupt blob

```
git fsck --full
  Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
  Checking objects: 100% (70321/70321), done.
  broken link from    tree 0716831e1a6c8d3e6b2b541d21c4748cc0ce7180
              to    blob 241091723c324aed77b2d35f97a05e856b319efd
```

Parent hash is **0716831e1a6c8d3e6b2b541d21c4748cc0ce7180**.

4) Get file name corresponding to corrupt blob

```
git ls-tree 0716831e1a6c8d3e6b2b541d21c4748cc0ce7180
  ...
  100644 blob 241091723c324aed77b2d35f97a05e856b319efd    dump.tar.gz
  ...
```

Find this particular file in a backup or in the upstream git repository (in my case it is *dump.tar.gz*). Then copy it somewhere inside your local repository.

5) Add previously corrupted file in the git object database

```
git hash-object -w dump.tar.gz
```

6) Celebrate!

```
git gc
  Counting objects: 75197, done.
  Compressing objects: 100% (21805/21805), done.
  Writing objects: 100% (75197/75197), done.
  Total 75197 (delta 52999), reused 69857 (delta 49296)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Step 4 resulted in `git ls-tree 9504a07fb803edfdf0c1dd99c5d561274af87982
error: Could not read 19505205fd1f219993da9b75846fff3cf432152d`, and I also tried it all over again without Step 2, and that resulted in `git ls-tree 9504a07fb803edfdf0c1dd99c5d561274af87982
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid stored block lengths)
fatal: failed to read object 19505205fd1f219993da9b75846fff3cf432152d: Invalid argument`

Answer (score 1):

Git checkout can actually pick out individual files from a revision. Just give it the commit hash and the file name. More detailed info [here.](http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/)

I guess the easiest way to fix this safely is to revert to the newest uncommited backup and then selectively pick out uncorrupted files from newer commits. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here are two functions that may help if your backup is corrupted, or you have a few partially corrupted backups as well (this may happen if you backup the corrupted objects).

Run both in the repo you're trying to recover.

Standard warning:  only use if you're really desperate and you have backed up your (corrupted) repo.  This might not resolve anything, but at least should highlight the level of corruption.

```sh
fsck_rm_corrupted() {
    corrupted='a'
    while [ "$corrupted" ]; do
        corrupted=$(                                  \
        git fsck --full --no-dangling 2>&1 >/dev/null \
            | grep 'stored in'                          \
            | sed -r 's:.*(\.git/.*)\).*:\1:'           \
        )
        echo "$corrupted"
        rm -f "$corrupted"
    done
}

if [ -z "$1" ]  || [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
    echo "'$1' is not a directory. Please provide the directory of the git repo"
    exit 1
fi

pushd "$1" >/dev/null
fsck_rm_corrupted
popd >/dev/null
```

and

```sh
unpack_rm_corrupted() {
    corrupted='a'
    while [ "$corrupted" ]; do
        corrupted=$(                                  \
        git unpack-objects -r < "$1" 2>&1 >/dev/null \
            | grep 'stored in'                          \
            | sed -r 's:.*(\.git/.*)\).*:\1:'           \
        )
        echo "$corrupted"
        rm -f "$corrupted"
    done
}

if [ -z "$1" ]  || [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
    echo "'$1' is not a directory. Please provide the directory of the git repo"
    exit 1
fi

for p in $1/objects/pack/pack-*.pack; do
    echo "$p"
    unpack_rm_corrupted "$p"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem by adding some change, like `git add -A` and `git commit` again.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by Daniel Fanjul looked promissing. I was able to find that blob file and extracted it ("git fsck --full --no-dangling", "git cat-file -t {hash}", "git show {hash} > file.tmp") but when I tried to update pack file with "git hash-object -w file.tmp", it displayed correct hash BUT the error remained.

So I decided to try different approach. I could simply delete local repository and download everything from remote but some branches in local repository were 8 commits ahead and I did not want to lose those changes. Since that tiny, 6kb mp3 file, I decided to delete it completely. I tried many ways but the best was from here: https://itextpdf.com/en/blog/technical-notes/how-completely-remove-file-git-repository

I got the file name by running this command "**git rev-list --objects --all | grep {hash}**". Then I did a backup (strongly recommend to do so because I failed 3 times) and then run the command:

"**java -jar bfg.jar --delete-files {filename} --no-blob-protection .**"

You can get bfg.jar file from here https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ so according to documentation I should run this command next:

**"git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive"**

When I did so, I got errors on last step. So I recovered everything from backup and this time, after removing file, I checkout to the branch (which was causing that error), then check out back to main and only after run the command one after each other:

**"git reflog expire --expire=now --all"
"git gc --prune=now --aggressive"**

Then I added my file back to its location and comit. However, since many local commits were changed, I was not able to push anything to server. So I backup everything on server (in case I screw it), check out to the branch which was affected and run the command "**git push --force**".

What I understood from this case? GIT is great but so senstive... I should have an option to simply disregard one f... 6kb file I know what I am doing. I have no clude why "git hash-object -w" did not work either =( Lessons learnt, push all commits, do not wait, do backup of repository time to time. Also I know how to remove files from repository, if I ever need =)

I hope this saves someone's time