# How do I restore a remote crashed Git repo?

Tags: git, restore, git-remote

Okay. We all know that every clone of a repo is good as a backup of the cloned repo. Fine. Also, every remote whose history gets updated with `git fetch` is backed up in that repo where `git fetch` was applied.

But when it comes to **restore** of the backup: **how do I do it?** What is the right opposite command of `git fetch`?

One of my Git repo has issues:

```
git status
fatal: unable to read tree 0d2f806b01ded93e76a6f2c7a68429939f483026
```

Yes, I could [start repairing the repo somehow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507463/how-to-deal-with-this-git-error), but – lucky me – I did a `git fetch notebook` on a remote machine right before my repo on `notebook` died.

So, I have a repo on `desktop`, where I have all the latest refs of my died repo (as `refs/remote/notebook/fix/issue1`, `refs/remote/notebook/master`, etc.).

How do I restore the repo on `notebook` with this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an easy way:

on `desktop`, ask git for the known remote branches of notebook:

```
git branch -r | grep notebook > notebookbranches
```

Now we have a file called `notebookbranches` that holds all the branches of the notebook.

On `notebook`, create a fresh empty repo called `myrepo2`

```
git init myrepo2
```

Add this repo as remote on `desktop`:

```
git remote add myrepo2 //notebook/D$/myrepo2 # working on Windows, use share name
git fetch myrepo2 # fetch current state of myrepo2
```

Now, open your favourite editor on the file `notebookbranches`. The file currently looks like this:

```
notebook/fix/issue1
notebook/master
...
```

Modify the file to look like this:

```
git push myrepo2 -f refs/remotes/notebook/fix/issue1
git push myrepo2 -f refs/remotes/notebook/master
...
```

Make this file executable and execute it.

When the script has finished, all the branches are present on the `myrepo2` repo but are stored under `.git/refs/remotes/notebook`.

Take all the files present here and move them to the `.git/refs/heads/` folder.

Then, you're done.

Comment: Easy enough method, probably easier than mine.  If for some reason the refs get packed (this could happen with a big enough repo), you can still use `git for-each-ref` (as I showed below) to re-create the branch names on the notebook.

Answer (score 1):

(1) On the desktop, clone the repo into a temp dir (where you will set all the branch labels the way you want them on the notebook).  Let's use a (bare) `--mirror` clone to make it non-tempting to fuss with a work directory, and to save some space, while also copying all refs in one swell foop:

```
desktop$ mkdir /tmp/for_notebook; cd /tmp/for_notebook  # or similar
desktop$ git clone --mirror /path/to/repo
```

Now that you have `/tmp/for_notebook/repo.git` (`--bare` and/or `--mirror` tends to add `.git`), set all the branch labels in this clone to match where they were on the notebook:

```
desktop$ cd repo.git      # i.e., /tmp/for_notebook/repo.git
desktop$ for refname in   # ok, now see below
```

Here's where you can either do things manually, or by script.  If there's a small number of branches you can just list them manually:

```
desktop$ for refname in fix/issue1 master; do
> git update-ref refs/heads/$refname refs/remotes/notebook/$refname
> done
```

If there are many, you can automate this with `git for-each-ref`, but it will give you long(ish, might as well just use full) names that require a little more shell scripting:

```
desktop$ for fullname in $(git for-each-ref \
> --format '%(refname)' refs/remotes/notebook/); do
> refname=${fullname#refs/remotes/notebook/}
> git update-ref refs/heads/$refname $fullname
> done
```

At this point `git branch` should give you just the branches you expect, but if there are extras, you can delete them with `git branch -d`.

(2) Now clone this to the notebook, as a new repo:

```
notebook$ git clone ssh://desktop.name//tmp/for_notebook/repo.git repo
```

This will no doubt set up the `master` branch already; you just need to add the other branches.  Re-updating `master` is harmless, so, same idea as before, except the remotes are now `origin/*` instead of `for_notebook/*`:

```
notebook$ for fullname in $(git for-each-ref \
> --format '%(refname)' refs/remotes/origin/); do
> refname=${fullname#refs/remotes/origin/}
> git update-ref refs/heads/$refname $fullname
> done
```

You probably want to tweak the config at this point, etc., so that you don't have `desktop` and `/tmp/for_notebook/repo.git` as `origin`.  (I usually do this by just editing `.git/config` directly.)  Compare with the notebook's original repo `.git/config` as needed.

(The old reflog is gone now, and any `git stash`es you had saved, as those were all local refs that did not get copied to `desktop`.)