# Missing tree object (broken link) in git bare repository

Tags: git

I keep a bare git repository (call it *mylibs*) on an external drive, in which I have a *dev* branch. I recently did:

```
git clone /media/extdrive/mylibs; cd mylibs
git checkout dev
```

And was surprised to receive:

> fatal: unable to read tree 03e99624424e6bd337ee16122567338751abef05

Running `git fsck` in the bare repository, reports:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
broken link from    tree 892d4fd7eb30964eb33de9ac707b4b0edbc919a5
              to    tree 03e99624424e6bd337ee16122567338751abef05
              missing tree 03e99624424e6bd337ee16122567338751abef05
              dangling blob e94d7824aca487641c11ff8312915fae5ef62cbe
              dangling blob 27afaaaa0f9979b4963d86bb1e5ddc3fe0d50d8b
              dangling blob e3d72157044f5b6808881025102764726f672d61
```

I know this topic has been discussed to death (ex: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507463/how-to-deal-with-this-git-error/1507935#1507935), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870895/how-to-diagnose-and-fix-git-fatal-unable-to-read-tree), [3](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#How_to_fix_a_broken_repository.3F)), but the answers which I have found all seem rather complicated, and a bit over my head. More importantly, none seemed to work (certainly because of something I was doing wrong, not because the answers were incorrect).

I have this repo cloned all over the place, and while I have no backups of the *bare* repository, the working clones are all up-to-date and **do** have the `03/e99624424e6bd337ee16122567338751abef05` object.

**My question is:** can I simply copy the `03/e99624424e6bd337ee16122567338751abef05` object directly from a working clone into the `.git/objects` directory of the *bare* repo on my external drive, or is that an incomplete procedure?

i.e. is this sufficient?

```
# assuming I'm in a working copy
cp .git/objects/03/e99624424e6bd337ee16122567338751abef05 \
   /media/extdrive/mylibs/.git/objects/03/.
```

The path `/media/extdrive/mylibs/.git/objects/03/` already exists and contains a few other objects.

*Notes:*

1. I made a copy of the bare repository, and tested the above and it seemed to work fine. But I want to be sure that I'm not missing something.
2. The .git/objects/pack/ directory is empty in the bare repository, and in all of my working clones. I don't know if that's indicative of anything, but it precludes use of some of the solutions that I have found.

Comment: Incidentally, I cannot imagine how the object went missing. I never had any interruptions during a push, and both repos are collocated on my system, so the transfer is practically immediate. The fact that this corruption (of sorts) occurred is a little concerning. Now I feel as though I'll need to periodically check that everything is still ok with my bare repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That ought to work, although it having the tree in place might reveal that you've got more missing objects (which you can just keep copying over). A tree doesn't contain anything that is specific to the location or configuration of the repo - it's just a list of names, hashes, and modes of the contents of a directory. However, you should check that both repositories have the same value for `git config core.compression`; otherwise, the copied file will be compressed at a different level than the repo expects (not sure if git can deal with that or not).

If that somehow doesn't work, you could try using `update-index` and `write-tree` to [manually recreate the tree](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects). Note that you can use `update-index` without actually having the files in the right state: you can supply both the mode, the sha, and the file name to `--cacheinfo`.

Comment: Thanks. It does seem to work, and luckily no other missing objects were revealed. After copying, `git fsck` returns no issues. I checked `git config --get core.compression` on both repos, and apparently the value is not set on either. So, I assume they will be equivalent.

Comment: Great! If it's blank, the default is [zlib](https://zlib.net/manual.html)'s `Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION`, which "requests a default compromise between speed and compression (currently equivalent to level 6)" (out of 1-9).