# git: local repository don't to do pull, but push successfully

Tags: git

We have a repository in our private remote server, and we use a local server to develop.
Now, have a problem when develop, some descriptions follow as:

A git repository called "test.git" in remote server, my colleague and I clone it to develop. I modify some files and push it successfully, my colleague also modify some files, but he have not to do pull and push it.

In this case, git will not be pushed successfully, but my colleague has  succeeded. I'm sure he didn't use command "git push -f origin master".

This operation cause remote repository be overwritten by his local repository history, so some modifications my push has disappeared.

```
Fetching remote heads...
  refs/
  refs/heads/
  fetch cdc059293a349ec0ba9dfd54f0f3d10fe19b23d8 for refs/heads/master
  refs/tags/
error: Could not read 9234f9acddff368f544f7613c2bf5b795d7b3713
updating 'refs/heads/master'
  from cdc059293a349ec0ba9dfd54f0f3d10fe19b23d8
  to   2cefa69d3c453c913a55d7172df406c00fdce89d
    sending 2 objects
    done
Updating remote server info
To https://XXXX.XXXX.com/git/test.git
   cdc0592..2cefa69  master -> master
```

have a error

```
error: Could not read 9234f9acddff368f544f7613c2bf5b795d7b3713
```

9234f9 is my modification but git do push continue. In normal case, git will reject push. It's very strange!
My git version is 2.22 but this situation the same even I have updated to 2.24 and my os use ubuntu 15.04.

Is there any way I can try it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with Git "Could not read" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507463/how-to-deal-with-git-could-not-read-error)

Comment: It looks like your server is using the so-called "dumb protocol": see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols - and using the dumb protocol is not a good idea, it has a lot of other traps as well. I suspect you are hitting one of these.