# github commits suddenly not showing up on live site

Tags: github

I'm making edits to a github website - i was able to make edits fine just a few days ago but suddenly the edits are not being reflected in the live website.   This never happened before, I made edits like this numerous times before.

[image]

I'm noting the above image.  What went wrong and how do i fix this?

Comment: github will prune ["orhaned"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092810/browse-orphaned-commits-in-git) commits

Comment: i didn't do anything differently this time.  I'm confused what's happening...