# Pushing app to heroku error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, push

I am getting the following error when I try to push my app to heroku.  I saw a similar thread on here, but the issues seemed related to OSX.  I am running windows 7

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 1652, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
fatal: object 91f5d3ee9e2edcd42e961ed2eb254d5181cbc734 inconsistent object lengt
h (476 vs 8985)
error: pack-objects died with strange error
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:floating-stone-94.git
```

I'm not sure what this means. I can't find any consistent answers on the internet.  I tried re-creating my ssh public key but still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recover the corrupted files.
[How to recover Git objects damaged by hard disk failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801577/how-to-recover-git-objects-damaged-by-hard-disk-failure)