# heroku corrupted object, git fsck fails in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pushing app to heroku error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948409/pushing-app-to-heroku-error)

Hello.  I am trying to push an app to heroku and I am getting the error detailed [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948409/pushing-app-to-heroku-error)

So I am trying to determine the corrupt objects using git fsck -full but it isn't returning anything.  Nothing happens:

```
Ryan@Ryan-PC ~
$ git fsck --full

Ryan@Ryan-PC
```

But I get the object error when I try to push the object to heroku.

Is there anyway I can go about repairing the corrupt repository, or can I just delete it and start over? How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Please just update the original question instead of posting a duplicate.  Editing a question bumps it back to the Active queue, so it will still get more page views.