# Git repository was suddenly broken

Tags: git, recovery

My git repository was suddenly broken. I had been working as usual, but when I typed in `git status` to see my changes, it said:

```
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
fatal: object 0dbfde4875a5f9c5fe25b4d1b9d34ab58986501e is corrupted
```

What can I do to recover my repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801577/how-to-recover-git-objects-damaged-by-hard-disk-failure has info that might be of assistance here.

There is also http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/recover-corrupted-blob-object.txt from the man himself.