# Git - corrupted object?

Tags: git, repository

My house just suffered a power-outage and now my git repo (which I was committing to when it happended) is reporting:

```
user@localhost$ git fsck
fatal: object 192e0282d23863ec80375a77011012ef8cb80f77 is corrupted
```

I can't commit because of this error. Pulling and fetching still seems to work fine.

```
user@localhost$ git commit
error: unable to find 192e0282d23863ec80375a77011012ef8cb80f77
fatal: 192e0282d23863ec80375a77011012ef8cb80f77 is not a valid object
```

I tried reseting it, but it didn't do anything

```
git reset HEAD 192e0282d23863ec80375a77011012ef8cb80f77
git gc
```

How do I fix this?

**UPDATE:** The files were still fine so I just cloned a new instance of the repo and manually moved the files over (Glad this wasn't the only repo instance!). However, I kept the broken repo so that I can try fixes posted here in case there is *a next time*.

Comment: +1 for having *incredibly* bad luck.

Comment: +1 for having a backup. the good thing with self-validating merkle tree is that they atomically validate themselves. The problem is, well... that they atomically validate themselves! This is a case of 'error detection' != 'error correction' and with a vengeance!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for suggestions on how to recover from this, see this thread: [How do you restore a corrupted object in a git repository (for newbies)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613682/how-do-you-restore-a-corrupted-object-in-a-git-repository-for-newbies)

Comment: I made it to the part about read-tree - but it failed.


    `user@localhost$ git read-tree 192e0282d23863ec80375a77011012ef8cb80f77
    fatal: object 192e0282d23863ec80375a77011012ef8cb80f77 is corrupted`

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you did with a new clone is probably the recommended way to fix it.  No sense doing something complex if you don't have to.  Those howtos are more for if you don't have the right version already in your working tree and don't have another clean copy.

Anyway, I think you wanted to reset to your last commit *before* the power outage, move the corrupted object out of your .git/objects, and try again.  It looks like your tree might have been corrupted, which is why the howtos geared towards recovering blobs didn't help.