# Recreate Git repo from multiple Branches

Tags: git, repository, branch, git-branch, fatal-error

I have a Git repo that has been acting funny.

I can `checkout` all of my `branch`es, I can work on each of them normally, and I can perform `gitk` to each one and view their individual `commit`s successfully — with one exception...

.... there is *one* `branch` that I can't seem to access.  With any action I try to perform that includes the flawed `branch`, I receive an error.

For example: `gitk --all` yields `fatal: blah blah blah` (as a side note, more details about the error can be viewed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9505097/102067), but I am trying to come by a solution from a totally different angle).

#### The Question

Is there a way to recombine all of the other, working `branch`es together such that I can use this repo again — only losing the `commit`s from the broken `branch` since the broken `branch` does not have any other `branch`es extending from it?

Comment: Nobody can help you if you give us the error message "bla bla bla"

Comment: @PaulBetts I completely understand, but that's not really important in the question.  However, if you, or someone else, feels that it may be relevant, I have linked to a question that containes much more information about it.  This question is more about combining `git` `branch`es into one repo.

Comment: Are you just asking how to delete your corrupted branch?

Comment: @PaulBetts Not exactly.  I have tried that, but the error won't allow me to do that.  I am asking if there is a way to create a new repo and populate it with `GoodBranchA`, then add `GoodBranchB`, etc. reconstructing my original repo, but without adding the branch `BadBranch`.

Comment: Ah, I see - just go into .git and delete refs/heads/BadBranch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a remote and push all your 'good' branches onto that `remote`.  Then in a new local directory, do a `git clone` of that `remote`.

After that, if you do `git branch -a` you should see all your local and remote branches.  You can create a local tracking branch for each remote branch with:

```
    git checkout -b branch remote/branch
```

After this, you should have a local repo with all 'good' branches.