# Git: failed to read object ... Invalid argument

Tags: git, recovery

I had this git message after a forced VM shutdown, which obviously corrupted the git index

`Git: Failed to read object abcdef.... Invalid argument`

I looked at these existing answers

[Restore a corrupted index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613682/how-do-you-restore-a-corrupted-object-in-a-git-repository-for-newbies)
[Recover damaged git by HD failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801577/how-to-recover-git-objects-damaged-by-hard-disk-failure)

None seemed to work.

Comment: Does a `git reset HEAD` helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets get into it and try to solve it. Use this approach only when `git reflog` also won't work, because obviously your index is corrupted, and reflog cannot read from a broken index.

Open your `.git/` folder

Look at the file called `HEAD`. 
This has the name of the branch your git is currently at.

Now look for a file called `ORIG_HEAD`. 
This `probably` has the SHA of the last good commit that git was able to register. If it is, Voila!

Copy it (say X), in terminal do: 
`git show X > interim.patch`

This copies your last successful changes into a standard diff.

Also copy this SHA (X) to `HEAD` file's contents. 
This tells git to consider this change as the current position, which it could live with, as it had registered it some time back.

By now if you do a `git branch`, you would have moved to `(no branch)`.

So now you have your changes. Do `git checkout -f <branch-name>` 
This will overwrite your changes with the remote contents, but you still have them in that patch.

So by now, you are

- onto a git branch
- git is restored

Do a `git apply interim.patch` which if goes through well, means you have your changes. 
Then go ahead with normal git steps.

- `git add .`
- `git commit -am 'Message'`

And you are back to normal peaceful life.

Answer (score 1):

Using @Arindam's answer above didn't work for me, but a variation of it did, I hope someone else finds it useful:

At this point you're in GIT limbo. You can't checkout a new branch with the state of the current branch, likely because the reflog is corrupted.

Before you continue:

- **Backup your project files somewhere else**
- Note down the last successful SHA1 from .git/logs/HEAD immediately prior to the one that GIT says it cannot find an object for (as per @Arindam above)

In my scenario I knew roughly when the files who's changes I had "lost" were last edited - approx 4 hours ago - so running the following fetches all my project files that were edtited between my last successful commit and now:

```
$> cd my/project/dir
$> find . -type f -mmin -240 -exec grep -l "$1" {} \; | xargs ls -l
```

- Note down the output of the find command into a text file somewhere as you'll be backing these up somewhere and you'll need to know which directories they came from to know where to copy them "back" to.

Copy these files somewhere else manually (e.g. into /tmp/backup) or by extending the command to do it manually (I had about a dozen, so by hand wasn't such a chore)

- Edit .git/HEAD and replace its contents with the SHA you noted down above
- Edit .git/ORIG_HEAD and do the same

  $> git branch

GIT should tell you "(no branch)"

```
$> git log
```

GIT should give you the log message for the SHA1 you noted above

Now create a new branch:

```
$> git checkout -b my_new_branch
```

Now copy all the files from /tmp/backup into their correct locations and run:

```
$> git commit -a -m "Some commit"
```

You're done. You should now be in a new branch called "my_new_branch" with all the files modified between the last most successful commit and now
committed and safe.

Now tar this lot up and back this up somewhere!

Answer (score -1):

Clone the project in another directory. There investigate whether you have all the refs that you had in the original.

Comment: The idea was to solve the existing corrupted commit. So that its not lost

Comment: -1: What if that's a large project? This is not obviously the solution.