# GIT fatal: failed to read object

Tags: git, github

I am a beginner in GIT and now I meet with a big problem. I commit and push some files in another PC and now on my home PC git is broken.

Please look below:

```
$ git status
fatal: failed to read object f4927c0e01f566faf3ef5cb55f974b524af4449c: Invalid argument


$ git commit -m "test"
fatal: failed to read object feb4df55618847c02cb13d334fdac4a313701aed: Invalid argument

$ git pull
fatal: failed to read object f4927c0e01f566faf3ef5cb55f974b524af4449c: Invalid argument

$ git add .
fatal: failed to read object f4927c0e01f566faf3ef5cb55f974b524af4449c: Invalid argument
```

and last one:

```
$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

Is it any possibiliti to repair my git?

Best Regards!

**EDIT:**
Just delete .git folder.
Change name of project folder
Clone from github
Add new files from my older folder.

I I could do this because I only added new files without any changes to the code.

Comment: Did you do `git pull` after pushing from another PC.   
 
[SEE THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739797/git-fatal-failed-to-read-object-xxx-invalid-argument)

Comment: I'm afraid, not. Can I do something else?

Comment: [See this Recovery method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11907655/4544967)

Comment: Is it the bare repo your trying to push your changes, or did your system just shutdown due to power shortage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the problem, **your facing is corrupted git repository**. It's something odd that many can face, one of the reason when the laptop or PC power outage can cause.

---

There are certain steps you can follow which can help you to solve the problem:

## STEPS

1. What you can do is to replace the object in `.git / refs / heads / my-working-branch" with ".git / logs / HEAD` and submit the successful object.
2. After step1 your `git status -s` and other commands to return to normal, you can use `gitk` or other gui tool or just git log will show you the commits.
3. Then use the `git fsck --full` command to see if there will be the same as the title of the error.
   If you found the problem then you need to delete the problem in `.git / objects /" .`
4. Then repeat the step 3, until there is no error with the title, to this Git repair is complete.

## For more information about fixing corrupted or broken GIT repo.

[Fixing broken GIT repo.](https://git.seveas.net/repairing-and-recovering-broken-git-repositories.html)

Comment: I don't understand the first step

Answer (score -2):

I was getting this:

```
$ git reset --hard
fatal: failed to read object d4578a93fd08f3b338937e33d75da98d9bf94d58: Input/output error
```

I used a Dropbox Rewind premium feature that I had on my Dropbox account and it was able to take my entire folder to a previous time when things were working. That obviously included the `.git` folder and everything in my Android app code/project.

[image]

This Dropbox rewind premium feature is awesome. Apparently those broken Git repository issues due to power outages or things like that are more common than I thought (https://git.seveas.net/repairing-and-recovering-broken-git-repositories.html).