# Git Repository giving error when I do git status

Tags: git

I did git status and I am seeing this error. How can I solve this please assist?

```
git status
fatal: bad object HEAD
git fsck --full

error: HEAD: invalid sha1 pointer 7b7cee7ecd496aa6a38d641a2a83480e4f68983d
error: refs/heads/master: invalid sha1 pointer 7b7cee7ecd496aa6a38d641a2a83480e4f68983d

error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry 7b7cee7ecd496aa6a38d641a2a83480e4f68983d
error: refs/heads/master: invalid reflog entry 7b7cee7ecd496aa6a38d641a2a83480e4f68983d
dangling blob f00de448e9864e419727a17ea2438514e1d10b1f
dangling blob c221f6bb2006ff58d8207e41527a1f3cd0bdf485
dangling blob e665c10c7fc97661dd3bd980b11ebeeab1649409
dangling blob 716af2645775c1594629e84463947c413e8b60c0
dangling commit dfaefd2f623dc3e2ecdfefe881f56cf4b3bc75c4
dangling blob aabb3d2087f289f1d1c01f13fbf897fb2436d0a7
dangling blob 3ad27c5164f7c03814cfdcce4a451be6926c4e5a
dangling commit f5d9fd4d24a3509fc5a53ca426d10541c94f8b79
dangling blob 4ef15c7ebb44c156dc01b881d8899a6f360464de
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git status shows fatal: bad object HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264032/git-status-shows-fatal-bad-object-head)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264032/git-status-shows-fatal-bad-object-head

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you restore a corrupted object in a git repository (for newbies)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613682/how-do-you-restore-a-corrupted-object-in-a-git-repository-for-newbies)