# git has a corrupted lose object that cannot be repaired

Tags: git

```
~$ git commit .
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
error: corrupt loose object '26f0654cde5d83f2ed8d971474d9d08a76644087'
fatal: object 26f0654cde5d83f2ed8d971474d9d08a76644087 is corrupted
```

The object in question doesn't exist and I've been doing commits every other day or so.
Since it doesn't list where this object supposedly is, I don't know what do with it.
I guess my last one was on teh 30th of last month, so I've been pretty off balance as of late but still I don't know why it's doing what it's doing right now.

I've tried `git unpack-object -r < objectname` and it does nothing. Since the object doesn't exist ANYWHERE on my hdd.

---

The original bit is now changed:

Nom, I've seemed to have just found it. I didn't realize that it was literally doing 26 as /26/ instead of itself. Apparently the file was made on the 1st of December and since I don't have said object since the last external backup, I believe was a few days before.
What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: If you have a backup, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801577/how-to-recover-git-objects-damaged-by-hard-disk-failure could help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: "Corrupt loose object"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254389/git-corrupt-loose-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to take a look at what object this is. You need to determine if it's a blob, tree, commit or (unlikely) a signed or messaged tag. Git has low level manipulation commands to do this.

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254389/git-corrupt-loose-object/4263009#4263009).

I would recommend doing a filter-branch or rebase -i --preserve-merges to clean up the history so all sha-1s resolve to proper objects.

Comment: i just ended up copying/replacing all files in the directory and i'm going to try it from there. And it's working again, sadly it's not able to fix the things but at least i did get it working and what you said might work in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
git stash
```

This worked for me.  It stashes anything you haven't committed and that got around the problem.