# Corrupted Git Branch after suspected hard disk issue

Tags: git, corrupt, hard-drive, git-branch

So I was having a problem with my hard disk (I think).  Everytime I ran git log commands (when running Windows through VMWare Fusion for Mac) it would throw a fatal error causing VMWare to crash (something about unable to reach disk drive).  Even if I booted to Boot Camp natively and tried running git log, I got some error about less.exe failing.

I couldn't copy/delete any files in the git/bin folder without problems (VMWare crashing).  So I tried to just install the latest git (1.6.7 from 1.6.4).  After doing this, I could successfully run git log commands again and everything seemed to be working.

Before the original crash had occurred, I had a branch I was working on that has a lot of changes.  Now when I try to checkout that branch, I get the following error:

error: unable to unpack d7a66a887fbe9b5f2baec0580da1fb4c1f39851e header
error: inflateEnd: failed
fatal: loose object d7a66a887fbe9b5f2baec0580da1fb4c1f39851e (stored in .git/objects/d7/a66a887fbe9b5f2baec0580da1fb4c1f39851e) is corrupt.

I get similiar error if I do git cat-file -t d7a66a887fbe9b5f2baec0580da1fb4c1f39851e.  I saw this on another post.  My branch had not been pushed to the network repository yet as I was only working on it locally.  Any chance of recovering/fixing this branch?  I'm desperate to not lose this code :(

Comment: Two things.  I forgot to mention that after my checkout fails, it almost seems as though git tries to apply many (or all???) of the changes from my dev branch to the master branch.  After the failed command, I still remain in the master branch but I have all kinds of changes waiting to be committed.  I revert them by git reset --hard origin/master then running a git clean -d -f.  Greg, fsck on the master branch before running checkout reports another error :( - fatal: loose object 3c93cf.. (stored in .git/objects/3c/93cf..) is corrupt.  So now my repo is even worse off than I thought?! :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [git has a corrupted lose object that cannot be repaired](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345622/git-has-a-corrupted-lose-object-that-cannot-be-repaired)