# Git branch corrupted

Tags: git

I shutdown my VM yesterday because of a freeze due to a compilation merge issue with RubyMine. Today I see that I can't merge master in the branch I was working on.

```
       Couldn't merge master
       error: object file .git/objects/c8/8d18e93e74011bf8cd130b260f74f0aaf78ee4 is empty
       fatal: loose object c88d18e93e74011bf8cd130b260f74f0aaf78ee4 (stored in .git/objects/c8/8d18e93e74011bf8cd130b260f74f0aaf78ee4) is corrupt
```

How can I fix this? I deleted both branch and checked them from the remote to "clean" the local but still the same.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with cached indexes, try looking up something on that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4348905/6309 could help?

Comment: I tried a few things but I just got my git messier. I'm going to delete it and checkout github to reset the local git. Hopefully I pushed everything before getting into trouble...

Comment: Deleting the whole project and checking from github worked, I won't shutdown my vm during merge anymore... Thanks.