# How can set an older commit to be HEAD?

Tags: git

I realized that I made some mistakes on HEAD, checked out an older commit and started coding from there. When I attempt a push I'm told that my current commit is behind and I need to merge with HEAD. Git recommends "git pull". However, HEAD has the code I want to ignore. How do I solve this problem?

Flowchart:

```
-------- HEAD (bad) ---------------------- + (behind conflict, requires
     \                                    /   merge with HEAD, which is
      \------- Current commit (good) ----/    bad and needs to be ignored)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If your repository isn't being used by other people, you can safely do `git push -f` to overwrite the remote branch.

Comment: -1:`git push -f` doesn't really go together with "safely"... I suggest you either clarify the pitfalls, or change the wording to something like "carefully" - the opposite meaning.

Comment: @ANeves I stand by my wording. It is completely safe if you are the only person using the repository. His stated intent is to *overwrite* the existing state of the branch on origin with his local work. This is *exactly* the purpose of `git push -f`.

Comment: I agree it looks like he just needs a `push -f`.

Comment: `HEAD` is an alias for the tip of the current checked out branch. If you check out another branch or commit then that will be `HEAD`. When you say `HEAD`, do you mean `master`? Did you make another branch from the older commit, and if so, what did you call it?

Comment: I agree that that is the purpose of `git push -f`, and that it is the solution in this case. But I disagree with the wording "safely", because `-f` is destructive and reverting accidents while using `-f` can be very difficult for someone who doesn't even know `-f`. (Speaking from past experience...) It's just a matter of the way things are written and suggested, I guess; perhaps I was too strong.

Comment: @ANeves You can disagree all you like, `git push -f` is still safe in this case by any sane definition of the word "safe".

Comment: @meagar I think you're misunderstanding the intent of StackOverflow. This is an information sharing and learning resource. You may be answering the OPs answer directly but this question and your answer will be referenced by potentially many future Google searches with issues that may not correlate to the question exactly. Your clear lack of detail to the answer you posted will likely cause others problems when they find your answer, which is exactly the opposite of the purpose of StackOverflow. It's fine to answer the question exactly, but you must provide details of its use. -1 for me as well

Comment: @searchengine27 Actually I'm a future "Google searcher" (actually I'm a Duck Duck Go searcher, so "Google search" is not a good term to use) and I found this answer very relevant and consider the warning included - I am the only user, so I consider it a good solution for my case. More detail isn't always better - succint is better. meagar specifically says "If your repository isn't being used by other people..." what more warning do you need?

Answer (score 158):

Here is what you can do:

```
git checkout <branch-to-modify-head>
git reset --hard <commit-hash-id-to-put-as-head>
git push -f
```

If you don't force the push, git will throw this error: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind.

Note that this will tamper your git history, so another way of doing this is revert each commit you don't want. That way you retain your history:

```
git revert commit-id
```

Cheers

Comment: and you will likely end up in detached HEAD at <commit-hash>

Comment: If you get "stuck" at detached HEAD at <commit-hash> after git push -f, just do git checkout <branch> to attach branch HEAD again.

Comment: `git revert commit-id` was best for me to ensure the changes were undone but not lost from the git history

Comment: `git push -f` doesn't work on git version 2.42. You'll get this error: `fatal: The current branch <YOUR-BRANCH-NAME-HERE> has no upstream branch.`

Answer (score 31):

The way I do it is:

```
git reset --hard <commit-SHA>
git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

It's the way git recommends and doing `git push -f` might be a little problematic for everyone else in the development team

Answer (score 12):

The only thing that worked for me:

```
git checkout <OLD_COMMIT>
git branch temp
git checkout temp
git branch -f master temp
git checkout master
git branch -d temp
```

Answer (score 11):

ANeves is right, "git push -f" only works because you were the only person using the repository.  This is not an acceptable solution for most people.

Here's your current commit history:

```
---A-B < HEAD (bad)
    \
     C < my_branch (good)
```

This has the solutions you want:
[How do I 'overwrite', rather than 'merge', a branch on another branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624357/git-how-to-overwrite-rather-than-merge-a-branch-on-another-branch)

To recap,

```
git checkout my_branch
git merge -s ours HEAD
```

This will stomp all the changes on HEAD's branch, and give you the following:

```
--A-B-D < HEAD, my_branch (both good)
   \ /
    C
```

D is effectively the same as C in this case, it just has different parents.

Comment: Do not use 'HEAD'. It should be 'merge -s ours oldbranch'. HEAD changes when you checkout.

Answer (score 4):

For those of us working on protected branches, push -f isn't an option.

Instead:

```
Checkout HEAD
diff {hash of desired commit to use as new HEAD} > myChange.patch
git apply 
commit 
push
```

If you have changes you'd like to merge into the new version of HEAD like OP, I would back them up first, correct the remote repo, then apply the changes.

This also preserves your repo history.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late to the party - I had to do:

```
git push -f origin HEAD:<name-of-branch>
```

[Please read the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---force) first before executing this command.

Comment: !!! WARNING !!! VERY DANGEROUS COMMAND !!! USE AT YOUR OWN RISK. THIS WILL ERASE ALL COMMITS UP UNTIL THE ONE YOU SPECIFIED IN THAT COMMAND.

Comment: Well too late for that. It erased all of my commits and i didn't plan for that. In this case i don't really care because those new commits have a lot of bugs so i am refactoring from the commit i want to set my head as. You should have wrote a big warning note to people that the command will erase all newer commits

Answer (score 3):

You can update the remote branch more safely with:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

If your remote branch has been committed to since your last pull, it will not reset the branch, but if this bad commit is the last commit, it will update the branch with your current version of the branch. (I've personally aliased this in my .gitconfig file:

```
[alias]
    please = push --force-with-lease
```

So I can just do

```
git please
```

at the command line. :)

Answer (score 2):

The steps that worked for me perfectly are following --

1) git log --oneline

2) Grab the commit that you want to rollback (most likely the commit before your last commit at HEAD and push)

3) git checkout  (this is the commit id to where you want your work to rollback to)

4) git push -f origin HEAD:master (-f will force the push overriding any rejection that would happen if pushed branch is behind the remote) 
HEAD:master(This is to ensure you are pushing the rollback to the master branch and at HEAD of the remote repo)

5) That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

This works best for me:

```
git checkout <commit-id> .
git add .
git commit -m "your changes"
git push
```

Note that the `.` is important.

Answer (score 0):

Rather use `git revert <commit-hash>` then force push. This keeps the history for others clean.

If you have a history: `A ---> B ---> C` and use reset you end up with `A ---> B` .
If you use revert you end up with `A ---> B ---> C ---> D` where D is the undo commit.

If you undo a merge commit you have to also specify the parent branch of the merge commit. `git revert -m 1` tells it to use the branch that was merged into. `m 2` the branch that was merged. Usually you use 1.