# Merging but overwriting changes in Git

Tags: git, conflict

When I merge a branch in Git to master I often get merge conflicts. Is there a way to merge a branch and just overwrite the stuff in the current branch?

Comment: You mean like in SVN - use theirs?

Comment: My experience with automatically choosing one side for a merge has never been good .. also, isn't it the point of merge conflicts to check what other people changed near the same lines as you before removing their changes?

Comment: It's me that made the branch locally in the first place.. it's just quicker than trawling through the file and removing the conflicts

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Add `-X ours` argument to your `git merge` command.

Say you are working in your local branch. Then you want to merge in what went in the `master`:

```
git merge -X ours master
```

On the other hand if you *are* in `master` and want to merge your local branch into `master` then @elhadi rightly says you should use `theirs`:

```
git merge -X theirs somebranch
```

Comment: @elhadi My understanding is that John Hunt wants to push *his* work, not theirs.

Comment: It was a local branch yes. Eg I've been working on somebranch and want to merge/replace somebranch files in place of the ones on master.

Comment: This still give the "files would be overwritten by merge" error instead of overwriting them with `-X theirs`.

Comment: Some of the files just stay as they are .. not sure why

Answer (score 10):

To overwrite your stuff in your branch and take their work, you should make

```
git merge -X theirs {remote/branch} --> example:origin/master
```

Comment: what does `--strategy=recursive` add here?

Comment: gives me `merge: origin/master - not something we can merge`

Comment: I think, your remote doesn't exist, see this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862933/how-to-resolve-gits-not-something-we-can-merge-error

Answer (score 0):

I have found merge doesn't really make the target branch a mirror copy of the source branch.

If that is what you are after, in order to get the branches 100% in sync I have used this procedure:

```
git merge -X theirs somebranch
git reset somebranch --hard
```

This will reset the state of the current branch to the HEAD of `somebranch` post merge.  In some cases, you might also want to cleanup your working directory if it is dirty with uncommitted files, the whole procedure would then look like this:

```
git merge -X theirs somebranch
git reset somebranch --hard
git clean -f
```