# Git - issue merging branches

Tags: git, branch

I'm not familiar with working on many branches in git. I have the branches `dev` and `dev-new-changes`, which is the latest one. I just wanted to overrite `dev-new-changes` onto `dev`, so I went to dev and executed `git cherry-pick <dev-new-changes-commit SHA>` but it gave me lots of merging problems (deleted files, both merged). Now I can't even go back to dev-new-changes as it tells me `error: you need to resolve your current index first`.

What is the easiest approach to solve it? I even thought of deleting my files and cloning from dev-new-changes again to my computer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might be helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624357/git-how-to-overwrite-rather-than-merge-a-branch-on-another-branch

Comment: I had read the accepted answer which didn't apply to my case, but the second actually worked. Thanks