# Merge with '-s ours' to copy master branch

Tags: git, merge

I am using a side-branch called `live-deploy` - for automated deployment on the server - and the `master` branch as main work-branch.

When something is ready to be tested live i will just overwrite the branch. The Problem is that i can't just reset it to master because the automated scripts can throw errors when i do that.

Now i tried to merge the branches using the `ours` strategy, i got that from this question: [How do I 'overwrite', rather than 'merge', a branch on another branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624357/git-how-to-overwrite-rather-than-merge-a-branch-on-another-branch)

```
git checkout master
git merge -s ours live-deploy
```

No errors and git tells me everything is fine but nothing happened in the `live-deploy` branch. For example, there was a line i removed in `master` and was still there in `live-deploy`. After the merge nothing changed.

Shouldn't it be the same in both branches now? I have the feeling i do it the wrong way. Is there another way **without** using:

```
git checkout live-deploy
git reset --hard master
```

Comment: You would want to merge the other way around and make sure you're checked out on live-deploy. And in that case, you'll want ``git merge -s recursive -X theirs master`` to show preference towards the master branch.

Comment: @jeff There's a difference between the `ours` strategy (which takes the whole `ours` tree) and the `recursive` strategy, which merges the trees and uses the `theirs` side in the case of a conflict.