# GIT: how to merge two branches without actually merging files (trivial merge)

Tags: git, git-merge

Is there a way in git to merge two branches without merging file? In other words just to draw the merge arrow.

Let say I have branches A and B. I need to merge branch B to A, but no need all the changes in B, but rather only need to link to branches together.

```
git checkout A
git merge B --no need changes
```

In general is there a way to merge two branches without submodules. I want to keep submodules as it is in Branch A and still need to merge branch B.

Comment: What do you mean by _"without merging the file"_?

Comment: What do you mean with just draw the merge arrow? A commit that has as parents the last commit in the two branches but the tree of one of the branches? Maybe you can describe your use case?

Comment: I just only need to create the commit graph. In other words  just need to draw a merge arrow without actually merging two versions together

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for `git merge -s ours B`, but your description is not entirely clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GIT: How to 'overwrite', rather than 'merge', a branch on another branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624357/git-how-to-overwrite-rather-than-merge-a-branch-on-another-branch)

Comment: I don't think you want to actually `merge` here. Can you explain what the result you're expecting is?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `git merge -s ours B` to perform a merge discarding any changes B would introduce. Still, the commits from `B` are now in `A`, however, the files are at the state of `A` before the merge.

Comment: Seems like using `-s ours` always adds a merge commit even ignoring the `--ff-only` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a real merge and run `git reset ORIG_HEAD --hard` to go back.

If you just want to have a try or study what happens after `git merge`, you could make a series empty commits by `git commit --allow-empty --allow-empty-message --no-edit` for several times. After you create the commits and branches, you can run `git merge` and use `gitk` or `git log --oneline --graph` to see the commit graphic.