# git fake merge (marking a commit as merged without a real merge)

Tags: git, merge, git-amend

Assume I have the following history in my repository:

```
     E--F
    /
A--B--C---D
```

And I want to modify it to be this:

```
     E--F
    /    \
A--B--C---D
```

I don't want to modify file content of revisions, I just want to "draw a merge arrow". How can I do this?

I tried to do this by the following commands:

```
git checkout D
git merge F -s ours --no-ff --no-commit
git commit --amend
```

But I got the following error message:

```
fatal: You are in the middle of a merge -- cannot amend.
```

I want to leave the commit information unchanged (author, date, message). The only thing I want to change is to add pseudo merge-info to the commit.

Comment: `git commit-tree D^{tree} -p C -p F -m message` and then do a hard-reset to the resulting commit.

Comment: just use `git merge -s ours F` taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37834841/2351696

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
git checkout D~1
git merge F -s ours --no-ff --no-commit
git cherry-pick D -n
git commit -C D
git branch -f D
git checkout D
```

Comment: What is `D` and `F`? Branch name or commit?

Comment: @abhiarora, `F` can be any of them (branch name or commit). `D` is supposed to be branch name. But `D` can also be commit, but in this case the last two commands (_branch_ and _checkout_) won't work. You'll have to create branch for new commit by yourself.

Comment: " You'll have to create branch for new commit by yourself." Didn't get this. Can you add more details in your answer?

Comment: @abhiarora, in case when `D` is commit (not branch), you'll get commits structure like it is shown on pic#2, but instead of commit `D` you'll have commit `D'`. And no branch will point to this commit. So you'll to create branch for this commit manually.
If it's difficult for you, just use `D` as branch name. Then all commands in the answer will work fine.

Answer (score 7):

[raul.vila's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858890/git-fake-merge-marking-a-commit-as-merged-without-a-real-merge#comment86733840_49858890) contains the answer: you cannot modify existing commit `D`.  There is no power on earth that can modify an existing commit: `git commit --amend` is a lie. :-)

There are several things you *can* do, though:

- You can make a merge commit that has `D` as one of its parents, and `F` as the other, using the content from commit `D`.  That is what this two-command sequence:

  ```
  git checkout D
  git merge F -s ours --no-ff --no-commit
  ```

  prepares to do (the final commit has been suppressed by `--no-commit` but the merge is recorded as being in progress).

  The problem, as you have seen, comes in when you go to use `git commit --amend`: `--amend` means *use `D`'s parent(s) instead of `D` itself as the parents* and this conflicts with the ongoing recorded merge of `F`.
- You can make a merge commit that has `C` as one of its parents, `F` as the other, and uses the contents (the tree) from commit `D`.  This might be what you want.  Note that there is no front end command for this, so you must build the new commit rather manually; and the result is what many call an *evil merge*.
- You can use `git replace` to make an additional commit that resembles `D` but has different parents, that Git will use *in place of* `D`, but *without actually deleting* `D` at all.  That is, the original graph remains in place (and can be viewed and used using `git --no-replace-objects`), but most commands, when they are about to use `D`, use the replacement instead.

  The advantage to this method is that it does not affect any existing clones.  The disadvantage is that no one else will *see* this replacement commit unless they explicitly ask to copy it to their own repository: the reference to the replacement exists under `refs/replace/`, which is not normally transferred on `git fetch` and `git push`.

[Raymond Chen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858890/git-fake-merge-marking-a-commit-as-merged-without-a-real-merge#comment86734690_49858890) contains a command that makes a new commit with parents `C` and `F` but using `D`'s tree.