# Pull Request on Azure DevOps to force replace instead of merging

Tags: git, azure-devops, version-control, branch, branching-and-merging

Our QA branch was broken and due to time constraints our team was pushing directly from Dev branch to production. Hence, our QA branch needs a reset. I want to know if there is a way to raise a Pull Request on **Azure DevOps** where the **source is "Production" and Target is "QA"** and **instead of merging**, all the files of "QA" should be **replaced by** the "Production" files. Kind of like making a copy of Production branch onto the QA branch.

**Note:** Making a branch of Production and making it the new QA is not an option due to external reasons.

Comment: Wouldn't local reset followed by force push work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the two branches `QA` and `Production` to be the same, you can tag the `QA` branch, then reset the `QA` branch to the `Production` one:

```
git checkout QA
git tag old-QA-branch
git reset --hard Production
git push origin QA --force
```

You can refer to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624357/how-do-i-overwrite-rather-than-merge-a-branch-on-another-branch-in-git) with similar issue for more solutions.