# Why would you ever do squash and merge on master when using GitFlow?

Tags: git, github, version-control

Our team has been using squash and merge religiously for the last two months as we heard it was best practice. But recently it was discovered that we were using it incorrectly.

Initially, I thought squash-and-merge just created a neat little wrapper commit for the commits in your merge but that is NOT the case. It creates a separate, unrelated commit. Therefore, after two months, even though our files were in sync between our 'develop' and 'master' branches, the commits were not -- so our PRs showed the entire set of changes that had been implemented during that time period. Needless to say, it was **impossible** to look at.

We resolved it by doing a rebase on 'develop' and release branches (which was SUCH a nightmare) and then, to make sure it didn't happen again, looked for a setting or configuration in our GitHub admin settings to disallow squash-and-merge on master but couldn't find one.

Given that that setting doesn't exist, my questions are this: If you are using GitFlow, would there ever be use case for squash-and-merging to 'master'? Seems like it's a function that should only be used between a non-permanent branch and a permanent one, and never between two permanent branches. If so, are there are steps or configurations you need so your branches don't get out of sync?

Comment: You could have avoided the rebase by doing a fake merge commit with [`git merge -s ours`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4624357/112968) – it creates a real merge commit, fixing the history, but doesn't change any of the files (which you don't need since all the changes are already there)

Comment: We did do a 'git merge master' on develop before rebase to grab the squash and merge commits which were putting develop behind by a few commits as well. But it didn't solve the problem I mentioned which was that all of the old commits were showing up in the 'files changed' as well. It was causing some heart attacks on prod release days. We definitely could have just proceeded with just the merge and done a normal merge for the upcoming release which would have solved the problem for future releases though.

Comment: *"If so, are there are steps or configurations you need so your branches don't get out of sync?"* What does this mean? Which branches, out of sync with what?

Comment: @user229044 The second question is dependent on the first. If there *is* a use case for using squash-and-merge on master, then how do you keep the 'develop' branch in sync with it? On all fronts but specifically around commits with what I experienced.

Comment: "[…] all of the old commits were showing up in the 'files changed' as well" doesn't make any sense. Files can show up in "files changed". Commits are not files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you are using GitFlow, would there ever be use case for squash-and-merging to 'master'?

No, you should never squash-and-merge your release branches or hotfixes into master.

> Seems like it's a function that should only be used between a non-permanent branch and a permanent one, and never between two permanent branches

Exactly right. You use it to merge a branch that you intend to delete, where you specifically don't intend to keep its history around. It's purposefully destructive, collapsing the whole branch down to a single commit on the destination branch. When you are done with a squash-and-merge, it will appear as though the work was done in a single commit directly on the destination branch.

Squash-and-merge is mostly for trunk-based development, where you continually merge small throw-away branches into a main branch.

> If so, are there are steps or configurations you need so your branches don't get out of sync?

No. Git-flow works fine, just don't squash-and-merge things you want to keep around.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I am not a big fan of gitflow and develop/master pairs.

But as far as I recall - You should squash and merge changes from your **feature** branch to **develop** branch. That creates one single clean commit for every pull request.
This make sense, as the feature work is iterative and pull requests can have several iterations.

when merging to master branch you should not squash the changes. That lets git understand that the commits are the same. This is very important in case of hotfix for example. Where you may push a fix only to master branch and then you need to merge back to develop branch.

As for "little wrapper commit", that is not how it works in git. Every commit is a snapshot, which includes its entire history. Every change to history (like rebase or squash) is inherently a new commit.

Comment: GitFlow is the standard at our company. -\\_(:/)_/- What is your preferred the alternative, out of curiosity?

Comment: Working with a single `master` branch and feature branches for developers. Leveraging CI/CD as much as possible. So each commit to master (PR merged) triggers deployment to test environment + tests. Without the intermediate `develop` branch.
Feature branches must be squashed to master to have nice and clean history.