# Forcibly apply one git branch to a second branch preserving the history of the second branch

Tags: git

I have a git repo with two local branches `dev` and `tmp`:

```
dev   A <-- B1 <-- B2 <-- B
        \
tmp      -- C
```

(`A` is the common ancestor for both branches)

Whilst on `dev` I would like to forcibly apply the state of the repo in `tmp`, e.g. end up with:

```
dev   A <-- B1 <-- B2 <-- B <-- D
```

Where `D` is commit `C` plus all the other changes necessary to force the repo to look like the `tmp` branch.

** **edit** **

To clarify the intent: a longer way to achieve this would be to revert all the commits from `B` back to `A`, then cherry pick `C` onto `dev`, e.g.:

```
dev   A <-- B1 <-- B2 <-- B <-- [(B1 B2 B)-1] <-- C
        \
tmp      -- C
```

... and then squash `[(B1 B2 B)-1]` & `C` to make `D` e.g.:

```
dev   A <-- B1 <-- B2 <-- B <-- D
```

Comment: Cherry pick C??

Comment: So is D equivalent to C or is D equivalent to B+D? Which history should be kept, there's only a single commit?

Comment: Might be of interest: [How do I 'overwrite', rather than 'merge', a branch on another branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624357/how-do-i-overwrite-rather-than-merge-a-branch-on-another-branch-in-git/4624383) (but I'm not sure what your goal is exactly)

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve? Why don't you merge tmp into dev or rebase tmp onto dev? Or cherry-pick the commits from tmp to dev?

Comment: @AJP sorry, I meant "D equivalent to B+C". But you haven't answered that question; is it equivalent or not? Because, if it is, then cherry-pick is the way to go. If it's not, you have to tell us specifically what the expected result is (i.e. how the resulting tree should look like; which files should be present in D, etc.)

Comment: @AJP And you want to explicitly hide that the old branch existed? Asking, because otherwise this would be covered by "overwriting" a branch (rather than merging).

Comment: (Sorry reposting this comment as I made a mistake and couldn't edit any more):  @knittl D would be the equivalent of C + the revert of B, hence cherry-pick or rebase won't do what I'm looking for.

Comment: Regarding "you want to explicitly hide that the old branch existed", I'm not sure I full understand what this would be.  I want to keep the commits A & B and add a new commit that is C plus the reversion of all the B commits back to A.  Hope that makes sense?  I've updated the question.  Thanks for all your help @knittl.

Comment: @AJP and you want to hide the fact that branch tmp (with commit C) ever existed? The new commit is not "C plus the reversions", the new commit is "a commit with the exact tree of C". If you can live with both branches being visible in the history, check out the linked "how to overwrite" question.

Comment: Right, I realise I've used the wrong language.  Thanks @knittl.  When I said "Whilst on `dev` I would like to forcibly apply the state of the repo in `tmp`" I did not mean the git tree & history, I meant the files and their contents.  Yes the "how to overwrite" sounds like that's what I need.  iBug's answer worked (minus last step getting wrong commit message) so not sure what to do with this question now.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the HEAD while keeping the index with a soft reset:

```bash
git checkout tmp
git reset --soft dev
git commit -C tmp
```

With the soft reset, you'll end up on `dev` but your working tree and the index will look exactly like those of `tmp`. And `commit -C` takes the commit message and authorship (and even timestamp) of the head commit of `tmp`, and make a new commit with all these information.

Comment: Did you try this? I don't think it does what you claim.

Comment: @matt Not tried, but I reviewed the man pages for reset and commit, and I think it's doing as the OP wants. Would you mind making it clear what could go wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what OP wants

Comment: No thanks, I think it's your job to check whether you are giving a correct answer. And besides, we have not ascertained what the question is, so this answer is premature (even if it were correctly describing what it does, which I claim it does not).

Comment: The suggested solution moves the tmp branch, which will then no longer reference C. Also, since tmp was already moved to dev, `git commit -C tmp` will just reuse the last commit of dev (because tmp == dev after `reset`).

Comment: iBug thanks, this is what I was looking for.  @matt knittl thanks for your help, comments & time, if anyone has suggestions on how to improve the clarity / wording of my question that would be appreciated.

Comment: @knittl yes you're correct that the `git commit -C tmp` part of this solution doesn't work yet as intended.

Comment: @knittl Thanks for pointing out. Somehow that part slipped through my mind. There sure is an easy fix, let me think about it.

Comment: There are many fixes, one of them being `HEAD@{1}` or `@{1}` for short.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the git rebase option to do this .

```
git checkout temp 
git pull origin temp 
git rebase C
```

This will apply the changes from source-branch which is C in this case to destination-branch which is temp , preserving the history of destination-branch. If conflicts occur, Git will pause the rebase process, and you'll need to resolve the conflicts manually.

```
git rebase --continue
git push origin temp
```

If you're working in a collaborative environment, consider using **git merge** instead of **git rebase**, as it creates a merge commit that incorporates the changes from both branches, preserving a clearer history.

Comment: Not what OP wants. `D^{tree} = C^{tree}` is what OP is looking for. Rebasing or merging will likely result in a new, different tree

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write commit `D` with parent `B` and the tree of `C` (i.e. `C^{tree}`, this can be done with the [`commit-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree) plumbing command:

```
git checkout dev
git commit-tree C^{tree} -p HEAD <<MSG
commit message here
MSG
```

I don't know how to reuse an existing commit message with `commit-tree`, but it is easy to amend this commit instead:

```
git checkout dev
git commit-tree C^{tree} -p HEAD -m 'overwrite with C'
git commit --amend -C C
```