# Why is the difference in commits of two branches is just stacking up when being merged? How to resolve?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-commit

Our team has our staging branch and our main branch for a specific project. And we are using GitHub. Now everytime we have to merge the changes from the staging to the main branch, the commit differences are just stacking up when we compare the branches the two branches instead of just showing the recent commits and the recent file changes. What is happening is that, on our next pull request of staging to main branch, after we merged the recent changes, when comparing the two branches, the previous changes and commits are still there stacking up with our most recent changes. Which it seems the previous changes are not merged. But it is. The fact is the merge commits are now working on the main branch. Even you manually look the codes in the main branch, you can see that the changes was merged.

This comparison or differences between the two branches which is seen everytime we need to merge a pull request gives us confusion which causes doubt and uncertainty in merging the new changes. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Please bear with my English as it is not my native language. And I am not sure with the exact terminology to use in this situation so I might have interchanged the use of the terms. But I hope I have at least delivered the message. If not, please feel free to ask more details you need.

We tried using different merging, like `squash and merge` and `create a merge commit`.

Comment: Are you squash merging? If you are.... then that's why.

Comment: @eftshift0 yes. Is there a way to resolve this and bring it back to a state where whenever we have new changes, the previously merged commits will not appear in the pull request where it seems it was not yet merged? Because all the previous changes also appear in the `Files changed`

Comment: @mykylesmile don't use squash "merges" (which aren't real merges). If you use regular merges, the behavior will be exactly as you expect.

Comment: that's right. The rule of thumb is to _not_ squash merges between long-running branches.... feature branches are fine to squash-merge as they die right there.

Comment: Let me write an answer so that I can provide a workaround for the next merge you will attempt so you can avoid having to go through hell _again_.

Answer (score 3):

So.... the problem is that you are squash-merging. squash-merging must be avoided if you are merging long-running branches.... if you are merging a feature branch, it's ok to squash-merge because the branch will die right there so not much of a problem.

Suppose you have something like this:

```
* JJJ (branch1)
* III
* HHH Merge of branch2 up to DDD
| * GGG (branch2)
| * FFF
| * EEE
| * DDD
| * CCC
|/
* BBB
* AAA
```

To explain the problem of the squash.... consider what the last common ancestor between `branch1` and `branch2` is. It's `BBB`, that's why every time you try to merge, you get all that *big* diff that you have gone over already with multiple conflicts every time.

So.... now, how can you get out of the situation *easily* for the next merge without having to redo all previous work, right? Ok... then let's try this:

```
git checkout -b temp HHH # create branch temp over the last squashed merge commit in branch1
git merge -s ours DDD -m "Merging DDD again"
```

Side note: Thanks to @knittl for providing the merge strategy there (One can still learn even after getting a nice git gold badge!).

After that is done, now `temp` is *almost* what the branch *should* have been like when you merged `branch2` into `branch1` the last time (I included `HHH` as a parent so it's not *exactly* the same that would have come up from the merge but alas).

```
* JJJ (branch1)
* III
| * ZZZ (temp) merging DDD again
|/|
* | HHH Merge of branch2 up to DDD
| | * GGG (branch2)
| | * FFF
| | * EEE
| |/
| * DDD
| * CCC
|/
* BBB
* AAA
```

Now, if you checked `temp`you will see that it includes both `HHH` and `DDD` as parents in the chart, just what we wanted..... now follow your normal workflow to get `temp` merged (**real merge!!!**) into `branch1` so that you get this:

```
* KKK (branch1) merge of temp into branch1
|\
* | JJJ
* | III
| * ZZZ (temp) merging DDD again
|/|
* | HHH Merge of branch2 up to DDD
| | * GGG (branch2)
| | * FFF
| | * EEE
| |/
| * DDD
| * CCC
|/
* BBB
* AAA
```

And, now... what is the latest common ancestor between `branch1` and `branch2`? Here's a tip: it's **not** `BBB`. It's `DDD`.

And from now on, do real merges between `branch1` and `branch2` and you won't be dealing with this problem again.

Comment: Thanks for this!! I will try this first and then will get back to you. But it might take a while. Thanks again.

Comment: eftshift0: that's a very complicated way to do `git checkout -b temp HHH && git merge -s ours DDD` (https://stackoverflow.com/q/4624357/112968)

Comment: `-s ours` does exactly that: use the tree of the current HEAD. »This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively ignoring all changes from all other branches.«

Comment: Disregard my previous comment (I deleted it). Hopefully you didn't read it and I will not be forced to admit that I was reading the wrong section of the `git help merge` page :-D (`ort ours`). Your advice seems to hold water.

Comment: Let me adjust the recipe with your tip... and thanks!

Comment: @eftshift0 no problem :D and yes `-s ours` is very different from `-X ours` (which is equivalent to `-s ort -X ours`. `-X` specifies a strategy option, whereas `-s` specifies the strategy itself.