# In git how to recover from a squashed git merge between 2 long lived branches

Tags: git, merge

I have `feature A` branch  and `master` branch, which are both long-lived.

In the distant future `feature A` may be merged back to `master`.

For now we want to keep `feature A` up to date with  `master`.

Normally we do `git merge master` and all is fine as we have the master's commits and an explicit merge commit.

A while ago someone merged from  `master` and **squashed the commits**, as advised against by https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#long-running-squash-merge

Now git thinks the common ancestor commit is older than it is, and git merges are very painful with weird conflicts.

I know I could create a new clean branch that is copied from master, copy over the delta between it and the latest `feature A` and use it in future and make sure all merges from master to it are not squashed, BUT is there any way to keep existing `feature A` keep using it for further work?

I did try `git cherry-pick X^..Y` to bring in comments from master but had to resolve unexpected conflicts there too.

Is there any reasonable way to keep using this `feature A` or do I have to clean it up its history and do a force push :-( ?

In other words if I've long-lived closely related branches with squashed commits am I better to start from scratch ?

Comment: You can recover the unsquashed branch in its entirety from GitHub (if this is GitHub — probably other PR-based hosts can do this too). And you can remove the unwanted squash commit (the false merge). And then you can merge the unsquashed branch properly.

Comment: @matt I had not thought of that but it is cool idea.

Comment: @matt unfortunately I think if I'd noticed the bad merge a few weeks  go I could have git reverted it and reapplied the gitlab merge request as you say. But since then other stuff has been committed so I cant not revert without many conflicts. I suspect this approach will work for other people but not me:-(  I guess I could cherrypick remove it and in its stead insert a unsquashed replacement (!!!) but then I'd have to do a force push on my feature branch which is not ideal either.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77919363/why-is-the-difference-in-commits-of-two-branches-is-just-stacking-up-when-being/77920793#77920793

Comment: Do you want to "fix" that with or without rewriting the branch's history?

Comment: @knittl - I would like to fix i without rewriting my feature branch's history i.e.  no force push. I am studying the answer that  eftshift0 provided (and I see you contributed to it too) - it looks promising albeit slightly intimidating :-)

Comment: +1 to @eftshift0 You re-merge with `-s ours` to say "Make no changes to the contents, but mark the branch as having merged this commit from the other guy (for the purpose of future merging)".

Comment: @eftshift0 I used the approach in your answer. It is an elegant & beautiful solution and works like a charm. I have my missing history back and I did not have to to a force push. Thank you so much!

Comment: The idea to use `-s ours` is @knittl's so that part is to his credit (and I noted it in the answer). I originally used a 3-command sequence to get the same result as `git merge -s ours`.

Comment: May we close this as a duplicate?

Comment: I think that's a fair assessment. Do you want to do the honors?