# TortoiseGit Error - Could not get all refs. libgit2 returned: corrupted loose reference file

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit

I just got an error after a recent commit using Tortoise Git:

> "Could not get all refs. libgit2 returned: corrupted loose reference
>   file"

which pops up when I go to check the Log.

Any ideas on how to rectify this?

Comment: having same problem...had to reclone whole repository, and now 1 day after it happens again :(

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at [Git: “Corrupt loose object”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254389/git-corrupt-loose-object) and [How to recover from a corrupt loose file in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650008/how-to-recover-from-a-corrupt-loose-file-in-git).

Comment: Also, maybe this will help?: [TortoiseGit - libgit2 returned: Refspec 'refs/heads/origin/HEAD' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575714/tortoisegit-libgit2-returned-refspec-refs-heads-origin-head-not-found).

Answer (score 23):

Your refs are stored inside the raw repository (in .git) in directories (named for each branch) under the "refs" directory. The problem is that one of these files has been corrupted. If you check the code [here](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/src/refdb_fs.c#L213) you'll see that the problem is either that the ref file is less than 40 bytes long, or has a 41st byte that is not a space (or tab, newline, etc). Search through the files in the .git/refs directory and you'll find the bad one. It should contain the 40-character hash of the commit which that branch refers to. You can safely fix it using Notepad.

Comment: Worked for me. I was able to copy the remote ref file over the local corrupted one and taadaa!

Comment: First of all, thank you cliffordheath ...
I got this error popping up after doing a **FETCH** with **PRUNE**. After reading your answer. I browsed through the branch ref files in *..\.git\refs\remotes\origin*.  
The **HEAD** file was being pointed to master branch as *ref: refs/remotes/origin/master*. In our repository the master/main branch is not master its another branch *ref: refs/remotes/origin/our-master*...  
Vola. It worked.... Thanks again @cliffordheath ...

Comment: After deletion of the master branch and changing the HEAD to anather branch on my remote Git-server repo by command `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/<your-master-replacement-branch>`. I got this error on local repos. Fixed by `git remote set-head origin <your-master-replacement-branch>` on any local repo. Or just do the git clone from scratch.

Comment: Work for me also, `.git/refs/heads/` inside this master file is look not good so update it with the same master file in refs and then done. issue solved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the use of "junction tool" (sysinternals). Got that error only when adding new sub directory and files. Using **git bash** the problem does not occur. Everything else works fine with "junction tool" and TortoiseGit ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error and managed to get my repo back without losing my changes.

I:

- Made several backups of the corrupt git repository just in case
- Cloned the lasted pushed version from the remote repository
- Copied all the files from the corrupt .git folder EXCEPT all files related to HEAD, FETCH_HEAD, ORG_HEAD etc ... the most important are the refs, obj, and index
- Ended up with a valid history, but corrupt index, applied the solution from this post [How to resolve "Error: bad index – Fatal: index file corrupt" when using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115854/how-to-resolve-error-bad-index-fatal-index-file-corrupt-when-using-git)

And my repository was back working ...

To make sure I did not push anything wrong, I cloned again from the remote, checked-out the changes I wanted to save from the restored repository, and comited them fresh.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after a hard reboot of my windows 10 machine in my local repo. The mentioned file (in the error dialog) contained only some 0x00 bytes where the other files in that folder contained a hash.

I just deleted that file, and the tortoise git log could open without error again.