# libgit2 returned: Refspec 'refs/heads/origin/HEAD' not found error in TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit, libgit2

I got this error when starting up TortoiseGit:

[image: Error dialog screenshot]

> Could not get all refs.
>   libgit2 returned: Refspec 'refs/heads/origin/HEAD' not found

While annoying, it does not prevent me from using TortoiseGit. However, I'd like to make it go away, because it is, well, **annoying**. How do I fix this?

Comment: I got this while changing my Github repo from Github flow to git-flow. I added 'develop' branch as my new default, and deleted the master branch. The accepted answer fixed this.

Comment: Created bug report: https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/2926

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Updated Answer

So it turns out that, for the purpose of updating ***a local repo's view*** of which branch `<remote>/HEAD` points to, you can have git automatically fetch that information from the remote and set it locally for you, instead of having to manually set it with `git symbolic-ref` like in my old solution below:

```bash
git remote set-head <remote> --auto

# Or shorter
git remote set-head <remote> -a
```

Note that this command ***doesn't actually change what the default branch is on the remote repo itself***. For that, you'll probably need to [use `git symbolic-ref` directly on the remote repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301956/git-correct-way-to-change-active-branch-in-a-bare-repository/3302018#3302018), if you have access to it.

- [Documentation for `git remote set-head`](http://jk.gs/git-remote.html).

### Old Answer

The problem that the error message refers to is that apparently libgit2 is trying to read the remote default branch pointed to by `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, but the remote branch doesn't exist, thus the error.

Using `git branch -a`, my local repo thinks that `origin/develop` is the remote default branch:

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
```

At one point `origin/develop` was indeed the default branch in my `origin` repo on GitHub, but it isn't any longer, the `master` branch is. The `develop` branch was deleted from `origin` since it was no longer needed.

So I fixed this by manually updating the local reference `origin/HEAD` to point to the new default branch on `origin`:

```
git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Or if I wanted to also add a message to the reflog for `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`:

```bash
git symbolic-ref -m "Update to new remote default branch" \
refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/master
```

This resolved the issue. See also:

1. [Documentation for `git symbolic-ref`](http://jk.gs/git-symbolic-ref.html).
2. [Git: Correct way to change Active Branch in a bare repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301956/git-correct-way-to-change-active-branch-in-a-bare-repository/3302018#3302018).
3. [How do I change a Git remote HEAD to point to something besides “master”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485578/how-do-i-change-a-git-remote-head-to-point-to-something-besides-master/1485590#1485590).

Comment: +1 I accidentally deleted origin/HEAD (yes, stupid!!!) and could restore it  thanks to your answer! :)

Comment: Thank you. I had to use `git remote set-head origin production` as there were `Multiple remote HEAD branches`.