# git "error: corrupt loose object" after moving a directory

Tags: git, corruption, data-recovery

I'm not sure if I had this error because I moved the directory that had all project files and .git but the error appeared around that time.

```
> git fsck 
error: corrupt loose object '25a196217ebb6e341909205575f491022eafc4d9'
fatal: loose object 25a196217ebb6e341909205575f491022eafc4d9 (stored in .git/objects/25/a196217ebb6e341909205575f491022eafc4d9) is corrupt
```

I searched for an answer and tried few things nothing worked.

[How to recover Git objects damaged by hard disk failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801577/how-to-recover-git-objects-damaged-by-hard-disk-failure)
resulted in

```
mv: cannot stat `.git/objects/pack/*': No such file or directory
fixgit.sh: line 3: tmpgit/*.pack: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `tmpgit/*': No such file or directory
```

`.git/objects/pack/` is empty. It puzzles me why it's empty.

`--full` option didn't help.

My next option is to revert and start over. And for the next time, I'll keep a backup up and will check git before backing up.

**Additional info:**
here is what i get when i look at the content of the object

```
> git cat-file -p 25a196217ebb6e341909205575f491022eafc4d9
error: corrupt loose object '25a196217ebb6e341909205575f491022eafc4d9'
fatal: loose object 25a196217ebb6e341909205575f491022eafc4d9 (stored in .git/objects/25/a196217ebb6e341909205575f491022eafc4d9) is corrupt
```

and type:

```
> git cat-file -t 25a196217ebb6e341909205575f491022eafc4d9
blob
```