# Git inflate: data stream error (invalid block type)

Tags: git

I'm trying sync my repository and I get this error:

```
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid block type)
fatal: pack has bad object at offset 117651801: inflate returned -3


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (3634297 ms @ 2/24/2014 5:43:22 PM)
```

I know in my repository exist some big zip files. I felling this is the problem.

- How I can fix it?
- Can I put this zip files on ignore list?
- How I know which files is the problem?

Comment: You have a network infrastructure problem.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/802297/6309 help?

Comment: Did you try [git-repair](http://git-repair.branchable.com/) already?

Comment: I think is not a network infrastructure problem, because I can do a Push+