# Git "inflate: data stream error"

Tags: git

After some fail event I can't commit anything, get a message:

> inflate: data stream error

when I execute git fsck --full I got the following:

```
$ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (317/317), done.
broken link from    tree 8a21a441e8554338d4e672d3040095a01ce2d881
              to    tree 2f20ed465d265d8d64e29e4b61774c679ebef075
dangling blob 2f05b905694c082d33967d7afbb86b1c0831503a
dangling blob 680849f611f724a578219f864c3c5ab4ddf10678
dangling blob ea8af1192b1f604f355767522e41426d5d3c8bfc
dangling blob 1092f8329a48f3e96bd4c25287776512c8907ef8
dangling blob 7e1d79cab8d7492e8d5254f6aa85dd953e836d47
dangling blob ee9d98c6286d32a491eb2d69011829682e54ffca
missing tree 2f20ed465d265d8d64e29e4b61774c679ebef075
dangling blob fe22d679f76de6990c1fe5b95d884032fda6eec5
dangling blob 692460aa49f3ef7efb13a4ed0387e3e284b3d67c
dangling commit 8ba6a5942ff6e165b4456361e8f26acb4ec7bef2
dangling blob 943c9c0de71cc5dd7bbe0ce6a1a43c56ad30f36b
dangling commit 16bd6c4078d2c3baa2fa3d7d60461f81d1411088
dangling blob 8248dd6edc73373088ac778221941eb2f9b02c9a
dangling blob bfc9b217a87dc836d580073e2d3f49b5f8fe3e84
dangling blob 5ecb1e64ec9a65d00cb6fa9ca3306d6a6f0e40d7
dangling blob 904cc189516b119a7cf6e0d91a9f9777665ff5b9
missing blob de4ce465cebd885428e4264822007995eddaf119
dangling blob 4ed263d5da3132f35d20ea683b9535c72a1d0831
dangling blob 7e53203bd6f5d6cc8483bceb2fe6c5841372e201
missing blob 45f2287bfa7ac5450d256f7648105dff2579d646
```

what is it and how to fix it?

Comment: @SamuelRobert, I seen that thread, I have another result

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/802297/4620609